# Split and replace a string with another string of same length in python

Tags: python, replace, split

I want to split the given string into letters,digits and special characters.
After splitting these have to be replaced by another letters,digits and special characters respectively.

e.g.  `abc123wer@xyz.com`  is the given string.Then

Splitted output: `['abc','123','wer','@','xyz','.','com']`

Replacing should happen from a file which contains some letters, digits and special characters.

Replacement output: `['xyz','231','etr','$','pou','#','fin']`

Answer (score 3):

One option to split the string is to use regex with `re` module to match *letters* `[a-zA-Z]+`, *digits* `[0-9]+` and *non-alphanumeric* `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` respectively:

```
import re

re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", s)
# ['abc', '123', 'wer', '@', 'xyz', '.', 'com']
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using regex for splitting but replacement of each string is a problem.

Comment: `code: for x in re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+|\\d+|\W+)',string):
    myList.insert(i, x)
   # print(myList[i])`

Comment: What is the replacement rule here?

Comment: i want to replace each alphabet,digit and special character with another alphabet,digit and special character of same length which are stored in a file.

Comment: I guess the best way here is to make a dictionary from the file you have, and then do the replacement by looking up the dictionary.

Comment: One side note here. you used `\w` which matches only letters, digits, and underscore, all special characters will not be matched. Is this what you need?

Comment: It is not `\w` but it is `\W` - which matches non alphanumerical characters.

Comment: I think we need more context, if you want the problem to be solved here.

Comment: [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157175/split-and-replace-a-string-with-another-string-of-same-length-in-python)  for the code.